# Assign identifier inside list comprehension/ mapping/ filter

Tags: python, list-comprehension, identifier

I want to pass a lambda expression to a filter that captures an outside variable `l`. I want `l` to be the list passed to filter. Assume that that list comes out of some other list comprehension/ mapping/ filtering. Is it possible to assign an identifier (in tis case `l`) to that list? Like so:

```
filter((lambda x : len([z for z in l if z == x]) == 1), l@[1,1,2,3,4,4,5,6,6] )
```

I just used `@` because in Haskell you can use `@` in a similar way.

Is there some succinct syntax for this or do I need to break up the operation into several lines and assign `l` in a normal manner?

Comment: It is not clear what the function should do. Can you explain?

Comment: Do you want a list that contains the content of list `l` at the indices in your list after the `@`?

Comment: @Graipher I simply want to bind the list after the @ to `l`. And to motivate this I said "assume that list is the result of some other computation, like a list comprehension".

Comment: @Don what function are you referring to?

Comment: Just pass it in, then? Either `filter(..., l)` or even `filter(..., map(...))` if you want to do it on-the-fly.

Comment: @Graipher But the list needs to be captured in the lambda and I want to bind it in-place, not outside the filter call/ comprehension/ mapping... whatever it would be.

Comment: So you are basically looking for the list comprehension `[x for x in l if l.count(x) == 1]`.

Comment: yes, logically that is equivalent... but `l` is being generated *inside* that comprehension in what I have in mind.

Comment: In other words, there is probably a different way to achieve what you want, which we could help you with if you showed some example input and expected output. If that list comprehension is not the solution you might have to write it as a generator, or an explicit for loop, or...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to give a name 'on the fly' to the second parameter of `filter`.

If even it were, I think that Python code should be more explicit (see "[The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)") and I suggest to split the code in two or more lines.